# Check a radio button in a JS return (inline)

Tags: javascript

Html Part

```
<div>Favourite pets?</div>
<input type="radio" id="check_dogs" name="pets_type" value="0" checked="checked" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">Dogs</input>
<input type="radio" id="check_cats" name="pets_type" value="1" onclick="ShowHideDiv()">Cats</input>             <hr>
<!-- Dog Name -->
<div id="dogs">
        <input type="text" onchange="auto_compile()" id="dog_name" placeholder="Name" />
</div>
<!-- Cat Name -->
<div id="cats">
        <input type="text" onchange="auto_compile()" id="cat" placeholder="Name" />
</div>
```

First JS script to check the radio button checked

```
function ShowHideDiv() {
        var check_dogs = document.getElementById("check_dogs");
        var dogs = document.getElementById("dogs");
        dogs.style.display = check_dogs.checked ? "block" : "none";

        var check_cats = document.getElementById("check_cats");
        var cats = document.getElementById("cats");
        cats.style.display = check_cats.checked ? "block" : "none";
```

The second JS script to autocompile

```
window.onload = auto_compile()
function content() { return `I love the ` + populate_field("dog_name") + ` so much`}
```

NOW i have to edit the second JS script, in something like this

```
function content() { return `I love the ` IF check_dogs.checked ` + populate_field("dog_name") + ` so much because the dogs are amazing` ELSE ` cats and my cat is named ` + populate_field("cat_name") + `! All the animals are great`}
```

In this way if I selected Dogs I see
I love the Kevin so much because the dogs are amazing! All the animals are great

and if I selected Cats I see
I love cats and my cat is named Marvin! All the animals are great

How to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this :

```
function content() {
  let msg = `I love the `;
  if (check_dogs.checked) {
    msg += populate_field("dog_name") + `so much because the dogs are amazing`;
  } else {
    msg += `cats and my cat is named ` + populate_field("cat_name") + `!All the animals are great `;
  }
  return msg;
}
```

Comment: Can I make it all in the return?

Comment: I am sorry, but that is not possible, unless you make variables for `populate_field("dog_name") + 'so much because the dogs are amazing';` and `'cats and my cat is named ' + populate_field("cat_name") + '!All the animals are great '`;.